# Replacing a file in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a standard Form to edit an object that has a file field in it. When I add a new profile, everything works fine, but when I want to modify a field, then problems happen: when I don't include request.FILES, all fields get retrieved in the form and can be updated with no problems, except the avatar (filefield), but when I add the request.FILES, fields are no longer retrieved in the inputs, and the form is not valid. What am I doing wrong?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.EmailField()
    avatar = models.FileField(upload_to="avatars/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Profile

class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["name", "email", "avatar"]
```

profile.html:

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row border m-3 p-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">Name</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">{{ form.name }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row border m-3 p-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">Email</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">{{ form.email }}</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row border m-3 p-5">
            <div class="col-md-6">Avatar</div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="{{ profile.avatar.url }}" width="100rem" />
              {{ form.avatar }}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

views.py:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = EditUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = profile_instance)
    context = {
        'profile': profile_instance,
        'form': form,
    }
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
        else:
            print("form not valid")
    else:
        return render(request, "app/profile.html", context)

    return render(request, "app/profile.html", context)
```

Comment: First, you need to set the (html) form's enctype to "multipart/form-data" (cf https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/), else `request.FILES` will be empty. Then you want to actually display the form's validation errors in your template. And finally, ou should ALWAYS redirect after a successful post (post-redirect-get pattern) to prevent duplicated submissions.

Comment: It's working now, thank you. No I had the enctype already in the code but the problem was the return render, I changed it to redirect and it worked. However, the first 2 fields (name and email) are not being populated in the form.

Comment: You should **not** instantiate your form with data if it's a `GET` request. That's because if you pass data (which you do by passing in `request.POST`) and the data is empty, your form is bound and the initial values are set to the data values. Please do **exactly** as shown in this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view): instantiate `EditUserForm(instance=...)` in case of `GET` request. And **only redirect** in case of a valid form.

Answer (score 0):

Special thank's to @bruno desthuilliers and @dirkgroten.
Here is the answer to solve the 2 problems:

```
def profile(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = Profile.objects.get(id=pk))
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
            return redirect('profile', pk)
    else:
        form = EditUserForm(instance = Profile.objects.get(id=pk))
    context = {
        'profile': Profile.objects.get(id=pk),
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, "app/profile.html", context)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try refactoring the code as follows: (edit it if I missed something. After form.is_valid, the same form should be sent in the context to display the errors.

```
def profile(request, pk):
    profile_instance = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = EditUserForm(instance = profile_instance)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EditUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance = profile_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.save()
            form = EditUserForm(instance = profile_instance)

   context = {
        'profile': profile_instance,
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "app/profile.html", context)
```

Comment: The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view) contain the exact code that is required to make a proper function-based view process a form. This answer is incorrect in that it doesn't redirect when the form is successfully submitted. You should **always** redirect even if it's to the same view.